# Can one compute $\log(-8)/\log(-2)$?

Tags: logarithms

Since the definition of a logarithm is :

$$y=\log_a x\hspace{0.1cm}\Rightarrow\hspace{0.1cm} x=a^y$$

Suppose we have :

$$(-8)=(-2)^3$$

Does this mean it is equivalent to:

$$\frac{\log(-8)}{\log(-2)}=3$$ ?

Comment: If you are working over the reals, no, what you have written is nonsense.  If you assume that $-8$ and $-2$ are complex numbers, however, you can make sense of things (though it is non-trivial to do so).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the definition of a logarithm is: $\;y=\log_a x\hspace{0.1cm}\Rightarrow\hspace{0.1cm} x=a^y$

The real logarithm is only defined for $\,x \gt 0\,$.

> Suppose we have: $\;(-8)=(-2)^3$.  Does this mean it is equivalent to: $\,\frac{\log(-8)}{\log(-2)}=3$ ?

Suppose we have $\,-1=(-1)^3\,$. Does this mean that $\,\frac{\log(-1)}{\log(-1)}=3\,$?

Comment: Is the second part the reason why real logarithms are restricted to $x>0$?

(Also, how do you cite part of my question? Been wondering how to do that for awhile now.)

Comment: Suppose we have that $1=1^3$. Does this mean that $\log 1/\log 1=3$? (Your post doesn't explain that the sign of the argument isn't all that matters.)

Comment: @ChungRenKhoo I assumed that you meant the *real* function logarithm. The [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Complex_logarithm) is a multi-valued function. The proposed equality doesn't hold as such in that context, either, but for more "complex" reasons (pardon the pun). `how do you cite` Start a new line with `> ` then what follows will be displayed as a citation. To copy/paste text from an existing post *into* the citation (including formatting and formulas), click `edit`, copy-paste the source text, then `cancel` out of edit mode.

Comment: @symplectomorphic The point you raise is about division-by-0 which is of course a valid point in general, but it is not particularly relevant in the context here. One has to worry that the two quantities are *defined*, first, before worrying that the denominator may be $0\,$. Besides, the crux of the question is not about fractions, but rather whether $\,\log x^3 = 3 \log x\,$ holds for negative numbers.